# How to use ColumnFilter or LightColumnFilter with angular-datatables error b.dataTable.columnFilter is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I want to use columnFilter or LightColumnFilter with angular-datatables but I get the following error `b.dataTable.columnFilter is not a function`

I know that in the website example https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withColumnFilter it shows that you need to add these scripts

```
<script src="vendor/datatables-columnfilter/js/dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/columnfilter/angular-datatables.columnfilter.min.js"></script>
```

But since these example was made a while ago I believe that the first script dataTables.columnFilter.js  it's no longer available in the later jquery datatables versions

I'm using `jquery Datatables 1.10.12` and

```
angular-datatables 0.5.5 and angularJs 1.5.7
```

this is how I'm creating my table

```
vm.dtOptionsEstatus = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data')
                    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                    .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
                    .withOption('stateSave', true)
                    .withColumnFilter({
                        '0': {
                            type: 'text'
                        },
                        '1': {
                            type: 'text'
                        },
                        '2': {
                            type: 'text'
                        },
                        '3': {
                            type: 'text'
                        },
                        '4': {
                            type: 'text'
                        }
                    })
                    // Add Bootstrap compatibility
                    .withBootstrap()


    // Active Responsive plugin
//                        .withOption('responsive', true)
                        .withScroller()
//                        .withOption('scrollY', 100)
                        .withOption('scrollX', 200)
//                        .withOption('bFilter', false)
                        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with library downloaded using bower. the library downloaded using following links fixed my issue.

```js
<script src="http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/vendor/datatables-light-columnfilter/dist/dataTables.lightColumnFilter.min.js"></script> <script src="http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/dist/plugins/light-columnfilter/angular-datatables.light-columnfilter.js"></script>
```

for more information https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/928

Answer (score 0):

The library `dataTables.columnFilter.js` is not part of the standard datatables plugins and so is not available on CDNs where you normally would get the other datatable plugins. You can get it from here https://github.com/RobinDev/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js/tree/master

Also make sure your app depends on the `datatables.columnfilter` module

```
angular.module('showcase.withColumnFilter', ['datatables', 'datatables.columnfilter']).controller('WithColumnFilterCtrl', WithColumnFilterCtrl);
```